# why does bliss os hang on boot with qemu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, qemu

Hey I tried building and running qemu installed bliss os and it hangs on startup.  I tried both sdl and gtk displays.

"Booting from Hard Disk..."

```
../qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine.qcow2 32G

../qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -name blissoss \
    -m 4096 \
    -smp cores=4 \
    -nic user,model=virtio \
    -drive file=alpine.qcow2,media=disk,if=virtio \
    -cdrom ../../../AG-10-Bliss-OS-android_x86_64-202010071034_k-kernel-5.8-si-next-rmi_m-q_dgc-q-x86-generic_gms_cros-wv.iso \
    -display gtk
```

Comment: Looks like your VM is trying to boot from hard disk instead of cdrom. Add `-boot d` option to your qemu command line.

Comment: thanks it now tries to boot from hard drive but still hangs "booting from hard disk..." (I installed blissos with cdrom then switched to boot -d after)

Comment: `-boot d` tells qemu it should boot from cdrom. When you have installed blissos to the virtual hard drive you dont need it anymore. Looks like this OS is not supported or requires some specific hardware.